# Hbase REST web service for fetching selective data

Tags: hbase

i am using H Base REST for exposing H-base tables as web service(Restful).Now i am parsing this response using SAX parser as the XML is expected to be huge because of big data handling. Is this the right approach. But suppose what if i do not want all data i want selective data only? using this we are getting all the data from h-base table.suppose i want data based on certain criteria e.g  all data from table based on a use rid.i do not know how to do this?
thanks

Comment: HBase rest is deprecated in favor of Stargate project[1], [2]. Are you using ** Stargate**?

[1] http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/HbaseRest
[2] http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate

Comment: Yes am talking about Stargate..

Answer (score 0):

You can use POP_HBase API and see the tutorial which lies inside it.